# Amcharts ampliar tamaño de nombre de opcion de la leyenda usando Clustered column chart con TypeScript

Tags: typescript, charts, amcharts

¿Cómo amplio el tamaño de la leyenda usando Clustered column chart con TypeScript?

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/clustered-column-chart/

ya que los nombres de mis series son grandes. Y no se muestran de forma completa.
Aquí les dejo la imagen de como se ve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo pude resolver.

```
chart.legend.labels.template.maxWidth = 150
```